# JPQL SQL Server CURRENT_DATE Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, date, jpql

Using Spring 4.3.0 and com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.2.1.jre8, I am trying to execute this SQL Server Query

`SELECT * FROM Message m WHERE m.time >= '2017-11-29' AND m.user_id = 2 ORDER BY m.time DESC`

I am selecting from an SQL Server Express table using a datetime column formatted `2017-11-29 03:56:34.375` using the JPQL expression

`SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.time >=`*dateexpression*`AND m.user.id = :userId ORDER BY m.time DESC`.

The message object uses column type `java.util.Date`, and inserts into the table fine.

I have found a number of guides / SO questions on the topic and none seem to work for me. In *dateexpression* I have tried:

- `CURRENT_DATE`, Incorrect syntax near the keyword ' CURRENT_DATE '.
- `CURRENT_DATE()`, No error but does not select any messages.
- `:today`, with `today` as a passed in parameter `java.sql.Date today = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());` (=> `2017-11-29`) no error but does not select any messages.
- `':today'`, giving `unknown parameter name : today`
- `{d ':today'}`, giving syntax error on the `{`.
- `{d :today}`, giving syntax error on the `{`.
- `GETDATE()`, No error but does not select any messages.

Answer (score 0):

`convert(date, getdate())` This worked, as usual found out when methodically detailing the question for SO.

Comment: Except for character-based datatypes, values stored in a database do not have any particular "format" - that is an artifact of the application you use to view information. Learn that and you will be a better developer. You should also get into the habit of reading the documentation first. There is no current_date function/global variable in tsql; it does have CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.